# Dcoder Challenge "Love For Mathematics": Only one out of three testcases correct

Tags: c, testing, testcase

I just completed a challenge in Dcoder using C. I got one correct test case out of three, and I can't seem to find the problem that prevents me from getting the other two test cases right as well. I'm still new to C, so please excuse if my code may look inexperienced. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the task:

> Problem Statement
>   Students of Dcoder school love Mathematics. They love to read a variety of Mathematics books. To make sure they remain happy,their Mathematics teacher decided to get more books for them. A student would become happy if there are at least X Mathematics books in the class and not more than Y books because they know "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy".The teacher wants to buy a minimum number of books to make the maximum number of students happy.
>
> Input
>   The first line of input contains an integer N indicating the number of students in the class. This is followed up by N lines where every line contains two integers X and Y respectively.
>
> Output
>   Output two space-separated integers that denote the minimum number of mathematics books required and the maximum number of happy students. Explanation: The teacher could buy 5 books and keep student 1, 2, 4 and 5 happy.
>
> Constraints
>   1<=N<=10000 1<=X,Y<=10^9
>
> Sample Input
>
> 5
>   3 6
>   1 6
>   7 11
>   2 15
>   5 8
>
> Sample Output
>
> 5 4

And here is my code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

typedef struct{
    int minBooks;
    int maxBooks;
} Student;

typedef struct{
    int books;
    int happyStudents;
} Happiness;

void fillarray(Student *arr, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &arr[i].minBooks);
        scanf(" %d", &arr[i].maxBooks);
    }
}

int getmaximum(Student *arr, int len){
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(arr[i].maxBooks > max)
            max = arr[i].maxBooks;
    return max;
}

Happiness *calchappiness(Student *arr, int len, int max){
    Happiness *re = malloc(max * sizeof(Happiness));
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
        re[i - 1].books = i;

        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            if(i >= arr[j].minBooks && i <= arr[j].maxBooks)
                re[i - 1].happyStudents++;
        }
    }
    return re;
}

Happiness getmaxhappiness(Happiness *arr, int len){
    Happiness re;
    re.happyStudents = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(arr[i].happyStudents > re.happyStudents)
            re = arr[i];
    return re;
}

Happiness getminbooks(Happiness *arr, int len){
    Happiness re;
    re.books = 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(arr[i].books < re.books)
            re = arr[i];
    return re;
}

Happiness besthappiness(Happiness *arr, int len){
    Happiness re = getminbooks(arr, len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(arr[i].happyStudents > re.happyStudents)
            re = arr[i];
    }

    return re;
}

int main()
{
    int len;
    scanf(" %d", &len);

    Student *students = malloc(len * sizeof(Student));
    fillarray(students, len);
    int happylen = getmaximum(students, len);
    Happiness *happy = calchappiness(students, len, happylen);
    Happiness output = besthappiness(happy, happylen);

    printf("%d %d", output.books, output.happyStudents);

    free(students);
    free(happy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did the two failed cases get the wrong answer, or did they just run out of time? Note that if `N` is 10000, and the maximum `Y` is 10^9, your code will take a very long time to run.

Comment: I just see a red marked X, so I don't know whether it just timed out or not. It could be a question of performance, though.

Comment: It's possible (dare I say likely) that the online judge has a one second timeout. The reason for a timeout is to reject code that gets stuck in an infinite loop, or hangs because the input handling is broken (waiting for input that will never come). Of course, that means that poorly performing code will also get rejected.

Comment: The approach I would use is to model each student as two events: a happy event (at count X), and an unhappy event (at count Y). Make an array of events, and then sort the array by the count. A single pass through the array gives you the answer. Since there are at most 10000 students, there are at most 20000 events, and the running time is determined by the time needed to sort the array of 20000 events. Which means you'll need an O(nlogn) sort. An O(n^2) bubble sort won't do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main() {
int N, i, j;
long int *X, *Y, books = 0, students = 0, happy;
scanf("%i", &N);
X = (long int*)malloc(N*sizeof(long int));
Y = (long int*)malloc(N*sizeof(long int));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%li %li", &X[i], &Y[i]);

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    happy = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        if(X[i] >= X[j] && X[i] <= Y[j])
            happy++;

    if(happy > students || (happy == students && X[i] < books)) {
        students = happy;
        books = X[i];
    }
}
printf("%li %li", books, students);
free(X);
free(Y);
return 0;
}

 //Try this one hope its help
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon, btw.